# Find all PPC libraries, binaries and applications in Snow Leopard

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard

Do you have any pointer on how to write a script that will search my system for applications, libraries (i.e. /usr/local/lib and /usr/local), and binaries that are PPC only?

I upgraded my system from a PPC Mac to a Intel Mac running Leopard 10.5. Then I upgraded to Snow Leopard 10.6 which doesn't come with Rosetta. So I'm only now realising all the old PPC things that are left on my system!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `file` command can detect what binary types are available in a file.

```
file -b /usr/bin/atrm
setuid Mach-O universal binary with 3 architectures
/usr/bin/atrm (for architecture x86_64): Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64
/usr/bin/atrm (for architecture i386): Mach-O executable i386
/usr/bin/atrm (for architecture ppc7400): Mach-O executable ppc
```

So, then, it is just a matter of using find and filtering appropriately.  Something like this should find all binaries on the system that have a PPC subsection.

```
find / -perm -u+x ! -type d -exec file {} \; | grep ppc | awk '{print $1}'
```

PPC only is a little more difficult.  For that, you'll want to do three commands to create 2 files in /tmp, the first containing a list of PPC files and the second a list of 32 or 64 bit x86 files.  Conveniently, 'ppc' matches ppc and ppc64.

```
find / -perm -u+x ! -type d -exec file {} \; | grep ppc | awk '{print $1}' > /tmp/ppc
find / -perm -u+x ! -type d -exec file {} \; | grep i386 | awk '{print $1}' > /tmp/x86
find / -perm -u+x ! -type d -exec file {} \; | grep x86_64 | awk '{print $1}' >> /tmp/x86
```

Then, sort/uniq a bit (just sorts the paths and makes sure each binary is only listed once):

```
cat /tmp/x86 | sort | uniq > /tmp/x86.filtered
cat /tmp/ppc | sort | uniq > /tmp/ppc.filtered
```

Then, use diff (and a bit more processing) to spew the list of files that are ppc only:

```
diff /tmp/ppc.filtered /tmp/x86.filtered | grep -e '<' | awk '{print $2}' | perl -p -e 's/:$//'
```

The end result should be a list of files that only contain ppc executable mach-o sections.  I would suggest verifying the list before nuking anything.

Some notes:

All of the above is done in the Terminal.

This is just a hack;  it worked just fine on my system and I'm glad you asked because I wanted to know the same.  But it is just a hack.

Comment: The following seems to work in only a single line, without traversing the entire file hierarchy:

    mdfind -0 'kMDItemContentTypeTree == "public.executable"' | xargs -0 -n 1 sh -c 'lipo="$(lipo -info "$1" 2>/dev/null)"; if [[ "$lipo" == *:*:*ppc* && "$lipo" != *:*:*i386* && "$lipo" != *:*:*x86_64* ]]; then echo "$1"; fi' sh

Comment: That surprises me not.  All of the above copy/paste into *my* shell.  *Your* shell may vary. :)  I'm using tcsh, btw.

Comment: Since `file` displays "`for architecture`..." for files with multiple architectures, take advantage of that to make an easy to understand one-line command that even works with recent versions of OS X like 10.11: `find / -perm -u+x ! -type d -exec file {} \; | grep -v 'for arch' | grep ppc | cut -d: -f1`

Answer (score 3):

To find Applications, you can use System Profiler (Called System Information in Lion).

Look under "Software" in the sidebar and choose "Applications"...then wait a long time while it gathers info.

Comment: To clarify: You can then sort the list by "Kind", which will list all PPC apps together.

Comment: Correct. I forgot that step. `:-)`

Comment: It's called "System Information" on Mavericks and later, too.

Answer (score 2):

Based on Kevin Ballard's answer, this one works in Mountain Lion:

```
mdfind -0 'kMDItemContentTypeTree == "public.executable"' | xargs -0 -n 1 sh -c 'lipo="$(lipo -info "$1" 2>/dev/null)"; if [[ "$lipo" == *ppc* && "$lipo" != *i386* && "$lipo" != *x86_64* ]]; then echo "$1"; fi' sh
```

Answer (score 1):

Also note Rosetta comes with 10.6 - it's just one of the optional installs.  Check the DVD that you used to install it with.

Comment: It can also install it from the internet if you choose to install it when trying to run a PPC-app.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, it should ask you to install it when you attempt to launch one of those applications.